# How get shared link in facebook feed? python, php Facebook API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

There is a lot of information that I share on facebook as 'I only see'.

The number is quite large, so I was always uncomfortable when I was looking for information.

So, I decided to create a tool to visualize my feed with my Facebook API.

PHP, and Python, I did not have much difficulty because I've been working on Facebook.

However, when I import the feed and check the object, the shared link in the shared post is not visible anywhere.

```
{  "data": [
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2018-02-06T02:16:22+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1246566978813633"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2018-02-05T11:25:51+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1246165258853805"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2018-02-01T09:40:55+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1243644729105858"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2018-02-01T06:54:59+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1243586515778346"
},
{
  "story": "updated his status.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-29T02:00:05+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1241513032652361"
},
{
  "story": "updated his status.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-29T01:58:33+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1241512265985771" },
{
  "story": "updated his status.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-28T11:07:39+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1241134576023540"
},
{
  "story": "updated his status.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-26T02:55:05+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1239634109506920"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-26T00:46:34+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1239582326178765"
},
{
  "story": "updated his status.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-25T04:50:18+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1239049139565417"
},
{
  "message": "Here is a blog post about auto posting on Facebook using PHP #php #facebook",
  "created_time": "2018-01-24T06:06:46+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1238462169624114"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-19T08:59:12+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1235165026620495"
},
{
  "story": "shared 카카오 인재영입's post.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-16T07:54:46+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1233260540144277"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-16T07:22:53+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1233251716811826"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-12T00:54:13+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1230667840403547"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-10T09:05:21+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1229686457168352"
},
{
  "message": "~ 2018.02.03",
  "story": "is at 김해국제공항.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-07T08:51:03+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1227934640676867"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-05T12:58:58+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1226809360789395"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-04T17:41:36+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1226344414169223"
},
{
  "story": "shared ExploitWareLabs's post.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-02T04:26:53+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1224800604323604"
},
{
  "story": "shared 메타분석 - 교육통계연구소's post.",
  "created_time": "2018-01-01T08:27:02+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1224308714372793"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2017-12-31T06:56:48+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1223494011120930"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2017-12-31T06:38:20+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1223486397788358"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2017-12-29T08:37:32+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1222432641227067"
},
{
  "story": "shared a link.",
  "created_time": "2017-12-29T08:35:49+0000",
  "id": "615192278617776_1222432211227110"
}
```

message, it does not seem to be a problem with the permissions.

Certainly, the title shared link also appears. Why can not I see the object for the shared link?

Comment: You need to _ask_ for the fields you want, otherwise you only get a couple of default ones.

Comment: @CBroe yeah, i want a shared_link about post~!

Comment: If you mean the URL that you shared in that post - that’s the `link` field.

Comment: @CBroe yes. right, but i was checked it. i didn't get data['link'] or anything

Comment: oh, i got it. your means! Thx!!!